# CloudFront to API Gateway request returns 403: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have an API Gateway fronted by CloudFront. The API Gateway has a regional endpoint with api key disabled. An Authorization header must be sent to the regional endpoint or the endpoint returns "Missing Authentication Token" as expected.

Using the same request on the CloudFront endpoint returns the following 403 Forbidden error:

```
{
    "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
     provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service
     documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST
    
    // sensitive data here...
}
```

The Auth token is created from an AWS signature. The signature originates from an IAM role that allows invocation on the endpoint: `"Action": "execute-api:Invoke"`

Any ideas on why CloudFront isn't able to use these credentials to hit the API Gateway endpoint?

In summary,

- "Postman w/ Authorization header -> API Gateway endpoint" works.
- "Postman w/ Authorization header -> CloudFront -> API Gateway endpoint" returns the above 403.

---

UPDATE: Adding information on how I obtain the signature.

IAM Role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:{ACCOUNT}:{ENDPOINT}",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

AccessKey, SecretKey, Session Token are obtained in CloudShell:

```
$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::{ACCOUNT}:{ROLE} --role-session-name {SESSION_NAME}
```

These 3 keys are then used in Postman's Authorization tab. I select "AWS Signature" type and provide the AccessKey, SecretKey, and SessionToken.

From here, I can hit the API Gateway endpoint and receive 200 response. With the same request and headers, hitting the CloudFront endpoint results in the 403.

---

UPDATE #2: Adding information on CloudFront configuration.

The distribution behavior for the API GW origin is using the CachingOptimized policy. Its also allowing all HTTP methods.

Comment: Presumably you are making some error in generating the signature.  But you did not share your code, so how are we to help?

Comment: How is that the case if Postman to API Gateway works, but Postman to CloudFront to API Gateway using the same signature does not? I'll update the question with new information.

Comment: Perhaps an error in the CloudFront configuration?  Which, again, you did not share...

Comment: Thanks. Is there a specific CF config setting you're interested in? I'm not sure what to even share.

Comment: I don't know anything about cloudfront.  But if that is the problem, then sharing your config is surely a good step to take.  In general, I would share any configuration details that seem relevant.  Particularly in how it communicates with the API gateway endpoint.

Comment: If communication A -> C works, but A -> B -> C does not, then it seems logical that the error must lie in B, or in its interfaces to A or C.